# How to play and pause the audio by using the media player?

Tags: android, media-player

I want to perform the three functions by using the single play button.
  First process - when we click the play button the mediaplayer should play the audio.
  second process - when user click second time the play button the audio should be paused.
  Third process - when user click the third time play button the audio should resume from the paused song.

The tried the below code

```
 if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
                    //  mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener((MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener) getActivity());
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mediaPlayer.start();

            }
           else if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }

            else if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() > 0) {
                long currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) currentPosition);
                mediaPlayer.start();

            }
```

The above code is not working ,please help me how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> try this way

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Button btn;
/**
 * help to toggle between play and pause.
 */
private boolean playPause;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
/**
 * remain false till media is not completed, inside OnCompletionListener make it true.
 */
private boolean intialStage = true;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    btn.setOnClickListener(pausePlay);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

private OnClickListener pausePlay = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (!playPause) {
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_pause);
            if (intialStage)
                new Player()
                        .execute("http://www.virginmegastore.me/Library/Music/CD_001214/Tracks/Track1.mp3");
            else {
                if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    mediaPlayer.start();
            }
            playPause = true;
        } else {
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_play);
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            playPause = false;
        }
    }
};
/**
 * preparing mediaplayer will take sometime to buffer the content so prepare it inside the background thread and starting it on UI thread.
 * @author piyush
 *
 */

class Player extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Boolean prepared;
        try {

            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(params[0]);

            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    intialStage = true;
                    playPause=false;
                    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_play);
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            prepared = true;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("IllegarArgument", e.getMessage());
            prepared = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            prepared = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            prepared = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            prepared = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return prepared;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (progress.isShowing()) {
            progress.cancel();
        }
        Log.d("Prepared", "//" + result);
        mediaPlayer.start();

        intialStage = false;
    }

    public Player() {
        progress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        this.progress.setMessage("Buffering...");
        this.progress.show();

    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to set DataSource in onclick it will take time to play because by this statement its take time to create connection with your server. and use of AsyncTask overcome the problem of hang it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
protected void initViews(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    oneTimeOnly = 0;
    mRootView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_digital_audio_content, this);
    btn_delete = (ImageButton) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
    tv_current_duration = (TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_current_duration);
    tv_total_duration = (TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_total_duration);
    seekbar = (SeekBar) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
    btn_Play = (ImageButton) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
    seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (mediaPlayer != null && fromUser) {
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    initMediaPlayer();

    btn_delete.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_Play.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void initMediaPlayer() {
    transactionDetail = FCSingleton.getTransactionDetails();
    TransactionDetail.DigitalContent digitalContent = transactionDetail.getDigtalContent(DigitalContentActivity.DigitalContentType.AUDIO);
    try {
        if (digitalContent != null) {
            Uri audioUri = Uri.parse(digitalContent.getmThumbContent());
            QLog.i("Play audio " + audioUri.getPath());
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, audioUri);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            updateMediaTime();
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                    finalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                    startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    updateMediaUI();
                    startTime = 0;
                    seekbar.setProgress((int) startTime);
                    updateMediaTime();
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        QLog.e(e);
    }
}

private void updateMediaUI() {
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        btn_Play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.digital_audio_pause);
    } else {
        btn_Play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.digital_audioplay);
        startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        seekbar.setProgress((int) startTime);
        updateMediaTime();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_delete:
            oneTimeOnly = 0;
            transactionDetail.removeDigtalContent(DigitalContentActivity.DigitalContentType.AUDIO);
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }
            ((ViewGroup) getParent()).removeView(this);
            if (mFragment.get() != null) {
                mFragment.get().removeDigitalContent(transactionDetail, DigitalContentActivity.DigitalContentType.AUDIO);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btn_play:
            if (mediaPlayer.getDuration() <= 0) {
                initMediaPlayer();
            }
            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                if (finalTime <= 0) {
                    finalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                }

                startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

                if (oneTimeOnly == 0) {
                    seekbar.setMax((int) finalTime);
                    oneTimeOnly = 1;
                }

                updateMediaTime();

                seekbar.setProgress((int) startTime);

                durationHandler.postDelayed(updateSeekBarTime, 100);
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                durationHandler.removeCallbacks(updateSeekBarTime);
            }
            updateMediaUI();
            break;
    }
}

private void updateMediaTime() {
    tv_total_duration.setText(String.format("%2d:%02d",
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) finalTime),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) finalTime) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) finalTime)))
    );

    tv_current_duration.setText(String.format("%2d:%02d",
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime)))
    );
}

//handler to change seekBarTime
private Runnable updateSeekBarTime = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (mediaPlayer == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            //get current position
            startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            //set seekbar progress
            seekbar.setProgress((int) startTime);
            //set time remaing
            double timeRemaining = finalTime - startTime;
            updateMediaTime();

            //repeat yourself that again in 100 miliseconds
            durationHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }else{
            for (int i = mediaPlayer.getDuration(); i >= mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(); i--){

            }
        }
        updateMediaUI();
    }
};

@Override
public void pauseMedia() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        updateMediaUI();
        durationHandler.removeCallbacks(updateSeekBarTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: How you are getting that pauseMedia override method?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
holder.btPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {


    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer[0] != null && mediaPlayer[0].isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer[0].stop();
        mediaPlayer[0].release();
        return;
    }
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer[]{MediaPlayer.create(context, soundUri)};
    mediaPlayer[0].setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {mp.start();
                                    }
                                });
    mediaPlayer[0].setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
           try {
               mp.release();
           } catch (Exception e) {

           }
           mediaPlayer[0] = null;
        }
    });
    mediaPlayer[0].setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            try {
                mp.release();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            mediaPlayer[0] = null;
            return false;}
    });
}
```

}